# In "Aliens", is there anything special about the date 6-12-79?

Tags: alien-franchise, aliens-1986

Within the "Alien" universe, does anyone know if there is any significance for the date 6-12-79 (USA format) in James Cameron's "Aliens"? Ripley quotes it as the date Burke informs the colony on LV426 to look for the derelict space craft from the original "Alien" film.

I know it's not the US or UK release date as claimed on some website. It may be nothing...

Comment: It was the release date for India

Comment: Related: [scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/10825/when-in-which-year-is-alien-set](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/10825/when-in-which-year-is-alien-set). This question has answers with assumptions to the timeline and statements to the year. The date is perhaps 12th June 2079 or 2179.

Comment: @IQV have read that question and disagree with you. Also it is 2179

Comment: @Valorum have just edited question to clarify in ment in-universe. Is India a bit Sci-fi market? Didn't think they need it!

Comment: @Seamusthedog - No, it's a relatively small market and in the late 1970s it was even smaller. I doubt that Cameron was referencing that.

Comment: @Valorum just a FYI, ta much.

Comment: I think the only significance is to inform the viewers that the order from Burke clearly came AFTER Ripley had been rescued. Meaning that there's no way Burke didn't know about the dangers Ripley was warning him about during the inquest, and therefore he effectively ordered the assured destruction of the whole colony by ignoring her testimony. But nothing about the date itself being special as far as I know.